# Using third party jars for my desktop app

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to build a desktop application using ibm rational software architect. The application works perfectly with the third party jar(Apache Poi) and produces an output.

When I export the source code into a jar, the third party jar is not included and the app does not work on the third party jar dependent place.

Third part jar is placed in c:/apps and
My source code is placed in c:/workspace/user/app

Answer (score 1):

You should set [classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) for your app.

This can be done by adding `-cp <path.to.you.3rdparty.jar>` to your starting command.

`java -cp c:/apps/* -jar <path.to.jar>`